# Reading and Writing std::vector<struct> to a file

Tags: c++, vector, struct, file-handling, read-write

I need to write a `vector` to a file, and then read it back into a `vector`.

The `vector` contains hundreds, possibly thousands, of `struct`s which each contain 2 different `struct`s.

I thought that the best way to do it would be to get the pointer with `MyVector.data()` and somehow write the data using that.

Just in case here's a diagram of the `vector`:

```
MyVector
    - Struct 1
        - Struct A
            - float
            - float
            - bool
            ...
        - Struct B
            - float
            - float
            - bool
            ...
    - Struct 2
        - Struct A
            - float
            - float
            - bool
            ...
        - Struct B
            - float
            - float
            - bool
            ...
```

and so on.

I tried multiple methods, such as `ofstream.write()` and `fwrite()`, but none of them worked.

```cpp
void PosBot::SaveMacro(std::string macroName) {
    int val = _mkdir("PosBot");

    std::string a = "PosBot/" + macroName + ".pbor";
    std::ofstream outfile(a.c_str(), std::ios_base::binary);
    std::copy(Frames.begin(), Frames.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(outfile));
    outfile.close();
}

void PosBot::LoadMacro(std::string macroName) {
    Frames.clear();
    Checkpoints.clear();
    CheckpointFrames.clear();
    std::string a = "PosBot/" + macroName + ".pbor";
    std::ifstream infile(a.c_str(), std::ios_base::binary);
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> iter(infile);
    std::copy(iter, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), std::back_inserter(Frames)); // this leaves newVector empty
    infile.close();
}
```

This gives me an error of:

> binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Frame' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: If the structs are POD then `outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(frames.data()), frames.size() * sizeof(Frame));` should work. Reading is the same, you just need to resize the vector first. I recommend writing a small header to the file that includes a cookie to identify the type, a version number, and the number of items. It'll be easier if you need to change something later.

Comment: How do I know what size to resize to if the number of structs in the vector changes

Comment: Write the vector size to the file, then read it back

Comment: Your call to `std::copy` hasn't decided whether you are copying `Frame`s or `char`s.  Just make them match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ostreambuf_iterator` writes character data to the output stream whenever it is assigned a single character via its `operator=`.  Since you are specifying `char` as the `CharT` template parameter of `std::ostreambuf_iterator`, its `operator=` expects a `char` value to be assigned to it (ie, when used to write data from a `std::vector<char>`, `std::string`, etc), but you are trying to write `Frame` objects from a `std::vector<Frame>` instead.  IOW, since you are trying to write `Frame` objects where `char` values are expected, that is why you are getting the conversion error on `operator=`.

You have a similar issue with reading in using `std::istreambuf_iterator`, too.  It is meant for reading in character data (via its `operator*`), not structured data.

For what you are attempting to do, you need to use `std::ostream_iterator` (and `std::istream_iterator`) instead. You will simply have to define an overloaded `operator<<` (and `operator>>`) for `Frame` to write/read its member data to/from a `std::ostream`/`std::istream` as needed.

Try this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Frame &frame) {
    // write Frame data to ostream as needed.  If Frame is a POD type,
    // you can write the whole thing in one go, eg...
    return out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&frame), sizeof(frame));

    // but, if Frame is not a POD type, you will have to write out
    // each data member individually instead...
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Frame &frame) {
    // read Frame data from istream as needed.  If Frame is a POD type,
    // you can read the whole thing in one go, eg...
    return in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&frame), sizeof(frame));

    // but, if Frame is not a POD type, you will have to read in
    // each data member individually instead...
}

void PosBot::SaveMacro(std::string macroName) {
    int val = _mkdir("PosBot");

    std::string a = "PosBot/" + macroName + ".pbor";
    std::ofstream outfile(a.c_str(), std::ios_base::binary);
    std::copy(Frames.begin(), Frames.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Frame>(outfile));
    outfile.close();
}

void PosBot::LoadMacro(std::string macroName) {
    Frames.clear();
    Checkpoints.clear();
    CheckpointFrames.clear();
    std::string a = "PosBot/" + macroName + ".pbor";
    std::ifstream infile(a.c_str(), std::ios_base::binary);
    std::istream_iterator<Frame> iter(infile);
    std::copy(iter, std::istream_iterator<Frame>(), std::back_inserter(Frames));
    infile.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I changed them to Frame and the comparison error goes away but no I get some other weird error.
`binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type '_Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion) C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include\iterator (297)`